# How to get user info using C# FacebookSDK

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to get user info using the FacebookSDK, but its not working.
This is what i try to do:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("my_access_code");

dynamic result = fb.Get("me");
var name = result.name;

MessageBox.Show("Hi " + name);
```

This is not working, because fb hase no get method. But every tutorial and code snippets i looked at are using get.

Is this code deprecated? If this is whats the new method of getting info?

Comment: Does it have GetAsync(...)?

Comment: no but it has GetTaskAsync().

Comment: That's what I meant but didn't remember the exact name - there should be the async version of the call for WP8.

Answer (score 0):

So, as we established in the comments - for Windows Phone 8 there are async calls that should be used instead of the old Get call. That's why you're not seeing the Get call, but the GetTaskAsync call. For this simple example, you use it the same way

```
dynamic result = await fb.GetTaskAsync("me");
var name = result.name;

MessageBox.Show("Hi " + name);
```

Other examples may vary. More about async calls with Facebook C# can be [found in the official documentation](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/making-asynchronous-requests/), but that's not exactly for the Windows Phone 8, but Windows Phone 7 which used a different async pattern. Still, it may be helpful to you. There's a [link to a supposedly more updated documentation](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/making-asynchronous-requests/Making%20Asynchronous%20Requests%20with%20async%20await) for async/await calls but for some reason I'm seeing a 'Page not found' error.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("my_access_code");

dynamic result = await fb.GetTaskAsync("/me");
var name = result.name;

MessageBox.Show("Hi " + name);
```